# ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server. No inicia proyecto Spring

Tags: api, spring-boot, spring

A modo de práctica empecé un proyecto Spring que desarrollé todas sus partes *(Entities, Repositories, Services, Spring Security, etc.)*, y al momento de ejecutarla el proyecto no arranca.

En la consola me aparecen varios errores y también la Excepción del título. Estos son los errores que aparecen:

> o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'securityFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'usuarioRepository': Error creating bean with name 'usuarioRepository' defined in com.mycompany.modelos.usuario.UsuarioRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'
>
> o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
>
> ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.

Y después de esa Excepción aparece primero en el Stack:

> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server

Asimismo, en el Stack también aparece lo siguiente:

> at com.mycompany.PeluqueriaCaninaSpringApplication.main(PeluqueriaCaninaSpringApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]

y al revisar esa clase en la línea 10 sólo tengo el método `SpringApplication.run(...)`. Esto es todo lo que tengo en la Clase:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PeluqueriaCaninaSpringApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(PeluqueriaCaninaSpringApplication.class, args); // Esta línea
}
```

Estuve buscando soluciones a dicha Excepción en diferentes páginas, pero lo que encuentro no es exactamente lo que me aparece en consola, por lo que no creo que sea el mismo error.

**EDIT 1**

Estos son mi Repository y las Clases de la configuración de seguridad respectivamente:

```
package com.mycompany.modelos.usuario;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

public interface UsuarioRepository extends JpaRepository<Usuario, 
Integer> {

UserDetails findByLogin(String username);
}
```

SecurityFilter:

```
package com.mycompany.infra.security;
import com.mycompany.modelos.usuario.UsuarioRepository;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;


import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class SecurityFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Autowired
private JWTService jwtService;
@Autowired
private UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    var autHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    if(autHeader != null){
        var jwt = autHeader.replace("Bearer ", "");
        var subject = jwtService.getSubject(jwt);
        if(subject != null){
            var usuario = usuarioRepository.findByLogin(subject);
            var autenticacion = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(usuario, null, usuario.getAuthorities());
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(autenticacion);
        }
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigando todavía más puede resolver la Excepción haciendo un escaneo de los Beans usando la anotación **@ComponentScan** en el main; con ésto, mi proyecto ya no presentó el problema :D

Answer (score 0):

te esta diciendo que tienes un problema en el repositorio. pon tu repositorio a ver como esta y pon todas las clases de seguridad.o es del repositorio o del filtro de seguridad el fallo
te dejo un link de mi proyecto con springsecurity para que compares
https://github.com/carlos033/ServicorRestConJjwt

Comment: Listo, Carlos, agregué el UsuarioRepository y el SecurityFilter en el post.

Comment: que lleva userDetails?xq devolver userdetails en una repositorio de usuarios? no se decirte el filtro xq es diferente al que yo tengo montado. ese finByLogin no me queda claro tine un campo que se llame login?xq si no debreia meter una query de HQL